# Duvida select em duas tabelas

Tags: php, sql

Estou fazendo um sistema em PHP, mas estou parado, pois não estou conseguindo encontrar a solução para um desafio.

Tenho 2 tabelas, uma chamada `objetos` e outra chamada `gavetas`. Eu tenho vários nomes de gavetas cadastradas na tabela `gavetas` e eu preciso saber quais delas possuem objeto dentro delas.

Estou tentando fazer um `select` onde independente de ter ou não objeto dentro da gaveta, traga todos os registros da tabela `gavetas` e as que tiver objeto, seja exibido o nome do objeto ao lado. E quando tiver ( Caneta ) dentro da gaveta o PHP imprime a palavra ( encontrado ) ao lado do nome do objeto. Já tentei `INNER JOIN / LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN`, mas não estou conseguindo o resultado desejado.

Tabelas:

```
**Gavetas**

id
nome-gaveta

**Objetos**

id
nome-gaveta
nome-objeto
```

Exemplo

```
Gaveta 1 / Caneta - Encontrado
Gaveta 2 /
Gaveta 3 /
Gaveta 4 /
Gaveta 5 / Borracha
```

Comment: ja tentou fazer um select usando full outer join? select from tabela  a full outer join tabela b on a.id = b.id, se possível poste o select q vc está tentando fazer.. abraços

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar um `LEFT JOIN` pra buscar na segunda tabela mesmo que não haja registros. Após isso concatene o resultado, caso queira uma linha por gaveta:

```
SELECT g.nome_gaveta,
       CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(o.nome_objeto SEPARATOR ', '),
       (SELECT ' - Encontrado'
          FROM objetos o2
         WHERE o2.nome_objeto = 'Caneta'
         LIMIT 1)) AS objetos
  FROM gavetas g
       LEFT JOIN objetos o ON o.nome_gaveta = g.nome_gaveta
```

Se quiser uma linha por objeto a `query` será a seguinte:

```
SELECT g.nome_gaveta,
       CONCAT(o.nome_objeto,
       CASE o.nome_objeto
         WHEN 'Caneta' THEN ' - Encontrado'
         ELSE ''
       END) AS nome_objeto
  FROM gavetas g
       LEFT JOIN objetos o ON o.nome_gaveta = g.nome_gaveta
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra solução, usando CASE ao invés de sub-select:

```
SELECT
    g.nome_gaveta,
    GROUP_CONCAT((
      CASE o.nome_objeto
        WHEN 'Caneta' THEN CONCAT(o.nome_objeto, ' - Encontrado')
        ELSE o.nome_objeto
      END
    ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS nome_objeto
FROM
    gavetas AS g
    LEFT JOIN objetos AS o ON g.nome_gaveta = o.nome_gaveta
GROUP BY
    g.id
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNZT8bSFPrcajmW89TZ6J2/0